# Twilio Status callback url

Tags: android, twilio

I am working on voice calling app which is built in java and I need to know the call status when it is picked , rejected or complated.My server end is in java.

I set status callback url while placing a call as mention in the twilio docs. My question which url is to added in that code and do i need to add the funtion for that end point url also.

And what should be the code in that funtion like what are the parameters as I need to print the call status

```
com.twilio.type.Client clientEndpoint = new com.twilio.type.Client("client:" + to);
        PhoneNumber from = new PhoneNumber(CALLER_ID);
        // Make the call
        Call call = Call.creator(clientEndpoint, from, uri).setMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                .setStatusCallbackMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                .setStatusCallback(URI.create("https://57fb8b2c.ngrok.io/events"))
                .setStatusCallbackEvent(
                        Arrays.asList(Call.Event.ANSWERED.toString(), Call.Event.COMPLETED.toString(),
                                Call.Event.INITIATED.toString(), Call.Event.RINGING.toString()))
                .create(client);

        // Print the call SID (a 32 digit hex like CA123..)
        System.out.println(call.getSid() + "//" + call.getStatus());
        return call.getSid();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm not particularly good at Java, but I can help with what happens when you set a [`statusCallback` URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/making-calls#statuscallback-parameter).

For each of the events you set as the `statusCallbackEvent` you will receive an HTTP request to your `statusCallback` URL when the call enters that state.

You will need to implement an endpoint (in your case, at the path `/events` as that's the URL you are setting) that can receive these incoming HTTP requests.

When Twilio makes the status callback request it includes [all the regular webhook parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/voice-overview#synchronous-request-parameters), such as `CallSid` so you can tie the request to the known call sid.

The request will also include some other parameters, most importantly in your case the `CallStatus` parameter. The value will be one of queued, initiated, ringing, in-progress, busy, failed, or no-answer. There's [more on what they mean here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/voice-overview#call-end-callback-statuscallback-requests).

I hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you.. I solve it by making  listening on callback event url.

Comment: Hey all, I think I am facing a similar issue with twilio where I can't understand how to parse the response I get back. Any idea/suggestion? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69898749/twilio-sms-status-callback-not-in-json